# English Keyboard Settings for OpenBSD 4.6

Tags: unix, openbsd

I am newbie to UNIX. I have had a decent experience with Linux but had to shift to UNIX. I am unable to type a C code in OpenBSD 4.6 in vi or mg editor or for that matter anywhere in the console because the '<' key or '(' key does not work. After a lot of research i found that there is a command called 'kbd' which can be set to use the required character set. But the keyboard encoding options are not clear.
It will be a lot of help if somebody suggests what steps can be taken.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was still true back in 4.6, but I'm going to guess it was: you set the keyboard mapping in `/etc/wsconsctl.conf`. Make sure you read `man wsconsctl` also.

Comment: PS: OpenBSD 4.6 is way way too old to be supported or even recommended. If you are afraid of newer versions being somehow bloated, rest assured that they aren't. I have 5.4 running on a Pentium II @ 300MHz with 128Mb RAM. No firefox, no heavy compiling, but works great for email or as an SSH client.